# page coming back with jQuery mobile virtual keyboard hide in Ipad

Tags: jquery-mobile

How can I prevent the page coming back with jQuery mobile virtual keyboard hidden in iPad? Because I'm having a list view popup with search box which sometimes disappears on input focus.

Comment: When you go back to the page can you not just call .focus on the input element?

Comment: $(window).resize(function (e) {    
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});//I added this code to revent it to happen